# cannot import name 'html5' from 'wtforms.widgets'

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am new to python and am using wsl3, Ubuntu 20.04.4, Python 3.8.10.

WTForms in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.0.1)

MarkupSafe in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from WTForms) (2.0.1)

> Error : cannot import name 'html5' from 'wtforms.widgets'

```
from wtforms.widgets import html5

class AssessmentCreateForm(FlaskForm):
    assessment_id = HiddenField('Id', default='')
    assessment_name = StringField('Name', default='', validators=[DataRequired()])
    test_type = SelectField('Test Type', coerce=int, validators=[DataRequired()])
    test_center = SelectField('CSEdu Branch', coerce=int, validators=[DataRequired()])
    year = SelectField('Year', default=datetime.date.today().year)
    term = SelectField('Term', default='')
    unit = SelectField('Unit', default='')
    test_detail = StringField('Test Number', default='')
    review_period = IntegerField('Review Period', default=7, 
    widget=html5.NumberInput(min=0, max=28, step=7))
    session_date = DateField('Test Date', validators=[Optional()])
    session_valid_until = DateField('Valid Until(Homework only)', validators=[Optional()])
    session_start_time = TimeField('Session Time')
    session_end_time = TimeField('Session Time')
    submit = SubmitField('Save')
```

wtforms-widgets is already installed and 'from wtforms.widgets' has no problem.

import wtforms.widgets and then print(dir(wtforms.widgets)) works.

Just 'html5' part has the error and it is unrecognised on the vs code even before compiling.

Comment: Don't repeat the question tags in the question title. It's enough when [python] and [wsl] are in the tags.

Comment: When you do `import wtforms.widgets` and then `print(dir(wtforms.widgets))`, what comes up? Also write down the exact versions of Python and of the relevant libraries.

Comment: My comment was not *"When you `print(dir(wtforms.widgets))`, what comes up?"*. Also, don't post screenshots of text. Post the text.

Comment: @Tomalak wtforms.widgets works. Just html5 has the error.